# selecting image from specific drawable folder in android

Tags: android

I have a Gallery widget that allows a user to select from a variety of images which I supply with the app. Because of different screen resolutions, I have different size images in different drawable folders. Eg drawable-large has 1280x800 versions of the images, drawable normal has 480x320. This is so the image looks good once selected on all resolutions.

The problem I am having is that the Gallery widget, on large resolutions, ends up using the 1280x800 versions of the images to populate the widget. With around 6 of these images, the VM heap memory becomes too large and the app stops working.

Is there any way to force loading images from a specific drawable folder?

I know I could easily solve the problem by adding extra images to my folders but I don't want to increase the size of my app too much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create aliases to your resources, see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AliasResources

You can then put all your gallery image that are used by multiple resolution in one place, so as to not have resource duplicate in your folders.

Comment: If I understand correctly, I would place xml files in drawable-large which referenced images in my drawable-normal folder?

Comment: Okay I have fixed the problem. In drawable-normal I renamed the images to `<imageName>thumb` and created an xml for each image with filename `<imageName>.xml`. Inside the xml I have `android:src="@drawable/<imageName>thumb"`. In this way, I can populate the gallery widget using references to `<imageName>thumb`. Once the image is selected, I can simply reference the image as normal and receive the correct size image. Thank you for the help Emmanuel

Comment: this does not provide a solution for ambiguous resources. There is no way to reference a specific resolution resource if there are multiple versions of it through the multiple environment folders, as there will be ambiguity when referencing it in the alias. Then again it's probably a system restriction that this happens, as there's a chance Android discards unsupported resource folders during installations (by the device)